# Complete mediation (Preacher Hayes)

Tags: regression, mediation

Below is the output of my bootstrap model (Preacher & Hayes, 2008). Path `a`, `b` and `c` are marginally significant (p < 0.1), but `c'` is not significant. I have read that when this is the case, there is reason to believe that there is complete mediation? Is that correct?

Thank you for your help!

```
Dependent, Independent, and Proposed Mediator Variables: 
DV =   Relation 
IV =   DummyRDn 
MEDS = Boardinv 

Statistical Controls: 
CONTROL = Numberpa 
          Priortie 
          Weighted 

Sample size: 101 


IV to Mediators (a paths)
             coeff        se         t         p
Boardinv    1,5302    0,8953    1,7090    0,0907


Direct Effects of Mediators on DV (b paths) 
             coeff        se         t         p
Boardinv    0,1160    0,0672    1,7255    0,0877


Total Effect of IV on DV (c path) 
             coeff        se         t         p
DummyRDn    1,1070    0,5959    1,8577    0,0663


Direct Effect of IV on DV (c' path) 
             coeff        se         t         p
DummyRDn    0,9295    0,5988    1,5523    0,1239


Partial Effect of Control Variables on DV 
             coeff        se         t         p 
Numberpa   -0,2421    0,1090   -2,2206    0,0288
Priortie   -0,2533    0,2173   -1,1656    0,2467
Weighted   -0,7825    0,2688   -2,9107    0,0045


Model Summary for DV Model 
  R-sq    Adj R-sq         F       df1       df2         p
0,2002      0,1581    4,7547    5,0000   95,0000    0,0006


************* BOOTSTRAP RESULTS FOR INDIRECT EFFECTS ************* 

Indirect Effects of IV on DV through Proposed Mediators (ab paths) 
              Data      Boot      Bias        SE
TOTAL       0,1775    0,1796    0,0021    0,1689
Boardinv    0,1775    0,1796    0,0021    0,1689


Bias Corrected Confidence Intervals 
             Lower     Upper 
TOTAL      -0,0197    0,7078 
Boardinv   -0,0197    0,7078 

******************************************************************

Level of Confidence for Confidence Intervals: 
95 

Number of Bootstrap Resamples: 
5000
```

Comment: Nothing is significant (at the 0.05 level). If you want to argue that the direct  effect is not significant, and can therefore be considered to be no different from zero, you're also going to have to argue that the indirect effect is meaningfully different from zero (even though it's not sig at the 0.05 level). You might argue that you're using 0.10 as a cut-off but that looks very like a post hoc alteration.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot assume a complete mediation.

For a mediation you would need a significant direct relationship between the IV and the Mediator (`a`), as well as a significant direct relationship between the Mediator and the DV (`b`).

In addition, the decrease of the direct relationship between IV and DV without the Mediator (`c`) and with the Mediator (`c'`) is rather small. In a complete mediation this difference should be larger and `c'` should be reasonably close to $0$. See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19729) for more information about testing for complete mediation.